# Как найти пересекающие данные в массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы, arraylist

Есть массив услуг, элементы которого тоже массив. В нем есть начало, конец, рабочее место, мастер.

```
[[1443646800,1443649500,4,4],[1443646800,1443649500,4,1],[1443646800,1443649500,3,4],[1443646800,1443649500,3,1],[1443650400,1443669300,3,4],[1443650400,1443669300,4,1],[1443650400,1443669300,4,4],[1443650400,1443672000,3,1],[1443671700,1443690900,3,4],[1443671700,1443696300,4,4],[1443675600,1443680100,3,1],[1443675600,1443680100,4,1],[1443680700,1443690900,4,1],[1443680700,1443690900,3,1],[1443691800,1443696300,3,4],[1443691800,1443717000,4,1],[1443691800,1443724200,3,1],[1443700800,1443717000,4,4],[1443700800,1443717000,3,4],[1443721800,1443724200,3,4],[1443721800,1443724200,4,1],[1443721800,1443740400,4,4],[1443727800,1443733200,4,1],[1443727800,1443733200,3,1],[1443727800,1443740400,3,4],[1443736800,1443737700,4,1],[1443736800,1443737700,3,1],[1443738600,1443740400,3,1],[1443738600,1443740400,4,1]]
```

На выходе хотелось бы получить такой массив  вида

```
[time: [[1443646800,1443649500],[1443646800,1443649500]], workstations : [1,5], workers: [1,3]]
```

где, time - это неповторяющиеся промежутки времени, workstations - массив рабочих мест , workers - массив работников

Не могу понять с чего начать? Я новичок в JS. КУда смотреть? Что в начале сравнивать ?

Comment: Начать можно со специализированных библиотек, которые умеют всячески работать с коллекциями. Это http://underscorejs.org/ и https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начать надо с того, что получаем на выходе. В JS `Array` не может содержать пары *ключ-значение*, для этого существует `Object`. В Вашем случае, объект будет выглядеть вот так:

```
var result = {
    time: [], 
    workstations : [],
    workers: []
}
```

Затем необходимо выполнить перебор всех элементов массива и для каждого элемента выполнить вставку в `result`. Сравнивать ничего не нужно, ведь формат данных одинаков для всех элементов.

Допустим, массив входных данных называется `data`, тогда перебрать все элементы можно так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    // элемент массива будет доступен как "data[i]"
}
```

Либо так, увы, работает не во всех [браузерах](http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach):

```
data.forEach(function(elem) {
    // элемент массива будет доступен как "elem"
});
```

Далее, для добавления в `result` данных, необходимо брать из элемента массива `data` необходимые элементы и добавлять их в соответствующий им массив. Например, для `time`:

```
result.time.push([data[i][0], data[i][1]]);
```

либо, если Вы выбрали другой способ перебора массива:

```
result.time.push([elem[0], elem[1]]);
```

Для того чтобы исключить дубликаты, надо проверить есть ли этот элемент в массиве и только тогда добавлять. Сделать это можно например функцией `indexOf()`. Эта функция принимает как аргумент элемент массива и возвращает его индекс, если он присутствует в нём или `-1`, если его нет. Тогда, если нужна проверка на дубликаты, можно сделать так:

```
!Boolean(~result.workers.indexOf(data[i][3])) && result.workers.push(data[i][3]);
```

Объясняю как это работает:

1. оператор `~` работает по такому принципу: допустим число равняется `n`, тогда `~n` будет равен `-(n+1)`, соответственно, если `indexOf()` вернет `-1`, то результат будет `0` иначе отрицательное число;
2. оператор `!Boolean()` приведет полученный результат к типу `boolean` и инвертирует значение (`0 == false`), можно использовать вместо этого *неявное* преобразование типов и написать просто `!` (`!~result.workers.indexOf()`);
3. оператор `&&` в JS возвращает не результат операции в булевой форме, а последний элемент, который может быть приведен к `true`. Это позволит добавить в массив элемент только в том случае, если его еще нет.

Comment: получается и проверят, если такой элемент есть - то не вставлять его в объект? через hasownproperty()?

Comment: @ennet, Вам же надо перебрать *все* элементы массива, ничего проверять не нужно

Comment: просто если я буду вставлять например, рабочих, разве там не будет дублей?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m8vxw3tb/ вот как-то так

Comment: @ennet, не понял вопроса, простите. Тогда надо ещё перед `push()` выполнять проверку на наличие в массиве. Например, через indexOf, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @ennet, дополнил ответ, Ваш пример будет [такой](http://jsfiddle.net/m8vxw3tb/1/)

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!!